# Set initial shared_prefs for preinstalled app?

Tags: android, android-source

I am building an Android image, and preinstalling an application with the following `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MyApplication
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com.foobar.myapplication.apk
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Now I would like to also preinstall some configuration files. For that, I have to copy files to `/data/data/com.foobar.myapplication/shared_prefs/`. I tried to do this via `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` in my makefile, however the files then don't have the correct permissions, and the application cannot access them.

The only solution I could come up with is to call a script from `init.rc` that populates my config file on first run. However, it would be tricky to create the config file as the correct Linux user for that app. If I manually use (for testing purposes) `chmod a+rw` on the file, it works as expected.

Is there any way to supply initial configuration for a prebuilt app?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would follow the usual approach for user-space apps, that is: let the app itself populate the initial shared prefs if the directory is employed when the app starts (often such heck is performed in onCreate() of all relevant activities).

This would resolve the issues like correct location, access permissions, etc.

The easy way is to bundle the defaults in assets.

Comment: I agree, that is the best solution. However, that only works if I have the source code of the application, and I have to understand and edit it. In many cases it would be easier if I could just configure manually, and then deploy the cloned configuration.

Comment: Oh, if you try to do that without access to the sources, and cannot edit the original APK, your task is more painful. With your kind permission, I will still leave this answer here, because it may be relevant to people who will be looking for ideas, but are luckier than you.

Comment: If you can repackage the APK, though, it would be reasonably plausible to extend the Application to perform initial population from assets (the latter must be added while repackaging). Don't forget the scenario when a user chooses to 'clear data' for the app: you don't want to teach `init.rc` to recognize this case.